# Is it possible to encapsulate a keyword into an Obj-C String by macro?

Tags: objective-c, c, macros

I want to use a static keyword in many place of an implementation file (.m file), and somewhere I need to use an NSString object of this keyword. So I want to use C macro to define a string object with the keyword. For example:

```
#define NSStringFromKeyword(aKeyword) @"aKeyword"    // This will not work

@implementation NSObject(NewCaterogy)

+ (void)load{
    NSLog(@"loading category name: %@", NSStringFromKeyword(NewCaterogy));
}

@end
```

On the Xcode console:

```
> loading category name: aKeyword
```

I want the results should be:

```
> loading category name: NewCaterogy
```

Is it possible to do this with C macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define NSStringFromKeyword(aKeyword) @#aKeyword
```

It's called [stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html)